# Add event listener to class inside table cells

Tags: javascript, html

Been stuck on this one for two days now (mostly due to reading a lot of links). I'm very new to web development...

This is what a single row looks like:

```
<tr>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="child" class="child" value={{ val }} placeholder="Search..." list="searchresults" autocomplete="off" /></td>                                    
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="test1" value = "test" /></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="test2" value = "True" /></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="test2" value = "False" /></td>
 <td>
  <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
  <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i> </a>
  <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
 </td>
</tr>
```

I want to add an 'onkeyup' eventlistener on each of the rows with cell values having class = "child" (or even maybe their using their IDs rather?). I have a loop adding multiple rows, so there will be multiple cells with class="child"

With the below code I can access the td values using querySelectorAll, but that's not exactly what I want and this is where I'm stuck now.

```
  document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr td')
  .forEach(e => e.addEventListener("keyup", function handler(event) {
    var results = document.querySelector('#searchresults');
    var templateContent = document.querySelector('#resultstemplate').content;

    while (results.children.length) results.removeChild(results.firstChild);
    var inputVal = new RegExp(search.value.trim(), 'i');
    var set = Array.prototype.reduce.call(templateContent.cloneNode(true).children, function searchFilter(frag, item, i) {
          if (inputVal.test(item.textContent) && frag.children.length < 6) frag.appendChild(item);
          return frag;
    }, document.createDocumentFragment());
    results.appendChild(set);        
  }));
```

Comment: You can specify only the 'child' classes in your selector `querySelectorAll('#myTable tr td input.child')`

Comment: Or just `querySelectorAll('#myTable .child')` No need to over-specify if you don't need to.

Comment: @IrkenInvader If I do var x = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr td input.child') and I log it to console I get back an empty NodeList...

Comment: Ah haha. That old nugget again. Does this help? "HTML elements can have more than one class name, where each class name must be separated by a space." Hint: Inspect Element on the target input and look to see what the browser thinks the CSS selection-path is. (It thinks it's an input.form-control)

Comment: You have class written twice on the child input, you want `class="form-control child"` instead of splitting them up

Comment: @DeanLambrechts I contributed a close-vote and a downvote, and a comment pointing out that there is not an actual question here.

Answer (score 0):

The following is working..
I was trying something like this my application, i'm sharing here incase anyone needs.

```
function onLoad(e) { 

    document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr td input.child').forEach(function(item, index){

        console.log(item);
        console.log(index);

        item.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
        console.log('index: ' + index);

      });
    });
}


window.addEventListener("load", onLoad, false);
```

EDIT:
This issue in the question lies with HTML, not the javascript

```
<tr>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="child" class="child" value={{ val }} placeholder="Search..." list="searchresults" autocomplete="off" /></td>
```

has 2 `class` attributes as pointed out in the comments
It should be..

```
<tr>
     <td><input type="text" class="form-control child" name="child" value={{ val }} placeholder="Search..." list="searchresults" autocomplete="off" /></td>
```